# submitting database information only after second click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good morning 
I have a rather strange occurance in  that information that I want to insert into a database is only submitted when I click a button control the second time. I disable the button after the info has been inserted into the access database and it is thus clear to me that the info is only submitted on the second click of my submit button. The event only fires the second time.
I did comment out all the code in sections such as a custom validator that I included on the page but it does not make a difference.

I stored some data into Session variables which I display in the textboxes when the page is loaded  to submit into the database and thought that this might be the problem and is not.
Removing the session variables and adding the info to the textbox manually also does not make a difference.

Is there perhaps insight as to why this is happening and how I could overcome this.

Kind regards
Arian

Comment: I believe only your code can tell the tale

Answer (score 0):

If you develop in Visual Studio just add a breakpoint onto the button click event and see for sure whether it is being submitted or not, you may find you've hooked your DB access in the wrong place.

Also, check your browser for javascript errors as those may cause flow to be different to what you expect